# VBA - Difficulties autofiltering worksheet with array

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I am trying to write a macro that opens another worksheet and automatically filters it when clicking on an element on a different sheet. The way this is supposed to work is the following:

```
Sub Link_erzeugen()
'
' Link_erzeugen Makro
'
' Tastenkombination: Strg+Umschalt+L
'
    Dim CostFactor As String
    CostFactor = ActiveCell

    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'2017 P&L'!A1", TextToDisplay:=CostFactor

    Dim CostElements As Variant
    Dim CostElementsNoSpaces As Variant
    CostElements = Array()
    CostElementsNoSpaces = Array()

    Dim MatchedCostFactors As String

    Dim myKey As Worksheet
    Set myKey = Worksheets("Allocation Key")
    Dim i As Long

    Dim strRange As String
    Dim Elements As String
    For i = 1 To 26
        With myKey
            strRange = Chr(i + 64) & "8"
             MatchedCostFactors = Range(strRange).Value
               If StrComp(MatchedCostFactors, CostFactor, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    Elements = Chr(i + 64) & "9:" & Chr(i + 64) & "22"
                   CostElements = Sheets("Allocation Key").Range(Elements).Value
                   Exit For
               End If
        End With
    Next i

    ReDim CostElementsNoSpaces(0 To 0)
    Dim Counter As Long
    Dim NoBlankSize As Long
    NoBlankSize = 0

    For Counter = LBound(CostElements) To UBound(CostElements)
        If CostElements(Counter, 1) <> "" Then
            NoBlankSize = NoBlankSize + 1
            CostElementsNoSpaces(UBound(CostElementsNoSpaces)) = CostElements(Counter, 1)
            ReDim Preserve CostElementsNoSpaces(0 To UBound(CostElementsNoSpaces) + 1)
        End If
    Next Counter



    Dim PandL As Worksheet
    Set PandL = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("2017 P&L")
    With PandL
       .Range("D1").AutoFilter _
      Field:=1, _
      Criteria1:=CostElementsNoSpaces, _
      Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
      VisibleDropDown:=True
    End With

    Worksheets("2017 P&L").Activate

End Sub
```

When a user clicks a cost element on the first sheet, the macro searches for the cost element's name on a different worksheet (Allocation key) and takes the values below the name once it finds it as an array. I then want to autofilter the sheet 2017 P&L with the values in the array.

So far, I have encountered quite a few issues and since I am very new to VBA, I would appreciate some help.

As it stands right now, the error that I face is that the run-time error 1004 is returned indicating the that the autofilter method of the the range object failed. I have been trying a few things, but I am really not sure how to fix this. It may be that the CostElementsNoSpaces array has only vertical values whereas the autofilter method demands horizontal values, so maybe transponing the variable may help. However, even if I simply enter a single value as filter criterion I am returned the run-time error.

Does anyone have an idea how I might be able to approach this?

Thanks a lot!

Leon

Comment: Does the filter work if you select D1 cell and select Autofilter? I ran test code and it fails if I try to set filter on incorrect range. I looked at the code, and didn't find any error.

Comment: On another note, you don't have to produce strings to refer your cells or ranges. `MatchedCostFactors = Cells(8,i).Value` would work fine.

Comment: I will try whether the filter works if I manually enter the value to filter for, however I would like it to filter automatically by the name of the element. My range may be an issue if the array to filter for has the wrong dimensions I feel.
Considering the second note: Thanks, I will try this, I declared the cells as strings to avoid issues if the respective fields are filled with text.

Comment: It's not what I meant. To troubleshoot, check if Autofilter turns on properly if you just click D1 and turn it on manually. This error usually means you want to call Autofilter method on incorrect range